# SQL unique query

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table with two columns ID,DESCRIPTION

the ID column in not unique.

I would like a DELETE query that will make the table have unique values in the ID column.

For example, if this is my current table

**ID      DESCRIPTION**

```
- 5     ABC
- 5     DEF
- 6     XDX
- 6     KKK
- 7     AAA
```

I would like to modify the table so it will become

**ID      DESCRIPTION**

```
- 5     ABC
- 6     XDX
- 7     AAA
```

(I want to leave only one row for each id, doesn't matter which row, can be the first row for example)

I am using mysql

Comment: Which RDBMS you are working with?

Comment: Do you want to delete the dups, or just omit them from a query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *"I would like a query that will make the table have unique values in the ID column."*

This will give you one record for each `ID`.

```
SELECT ID, MIN(Description) Description
FROM   tableName
GROUP  BY ID
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/397bb/1)

---

Here's a delete statement to remove duplicate `ID`, leaving only unique `ID` on the table.

**WARNING: this will delete records from your table.**

```
DELETE  a
FROM    tableName a
        LEFT JOIN
        (
            SELECT ID, MIN(Description) Description
            FROM   tableName
            GROUP  BY ID
        ) b ON a.ID = b.ID AND
                a.Description = b.Description
WHERE   b.ID IS NULL
```

- [SQLFiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b842d/2)

Comment: if you want to drop some duplicate `ID`, can you tell me what RDBMS you are using?

Comment: @CRDave - You mean delete but the given statement can be used *(easy or hard depending on dbengine)* to delete records. OP should mention the dbms.

Comment: You are right deleting is now proper way to make ID unique. But it look like he need it in this way or he want to learn. Lets see what he reply.

Answer (score 1):

Uthe most elegant way is to use mysql's multiple-table delete syntax and join the table to itself:

```
delete d
from mytable t
join mytable d on d.id = t.id
  and d.description > t.description
```

The key part of this query is the greater-than comparison of `description`, which not only stops same-row joins but also predictably selects the duplicate to delete.

Answer (score 0):

In PostgreSQL, you can do this.

```
delete 
from table1
where (id, description) not in
  (select id, min(description)
   from table1
   group by id);
```

I'll look to see whether MySQL supports row constructors.

(Later: MySQL *does* support row constructors, but has [another limitation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/delete.html) that prevents this from working. "Currently, you cannot delete from a table and select from the same table in a subquery.")

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what you actually need..try it
[delete duplicate rows from table](http://www.databasejournal.com/features/mysql/article.php/10897_2201621_2/Deleting-Duplicate-Rows-in-a-MySQL-Database.htm)